# error while installing mySQL in ubuntu 20.04[POP-OS]

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I deleted the file oracle-java11-installer-local but i messed my system up. I now cant install mySQL and it is giving errors

here is what happens... [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waDix.png)

```
~ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.21-1ubuntu18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up oracle-java11-installer-local (11.0.8-1~linuxuprising0) ...
Before installing this package,
please download the Oracle JDK 11 .tar.gz file
with the same version as this package (version 11.0.4),
and place it in /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local,

E.g.:
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.8_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script subpro
cess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The screen shot says following things --

1. mysql 8 is already installed.
   Please check the output of the following command
   `ps aux | grep mysql`
2. Trying to install java 11 and reached the error in package repository.

Comment: thanks!  I solved it, i was not actually reading the errors, it was pretty straight forward after i read them